# linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list

there are huge number of data, there are various groups. i want to check whether the new data fits in any group and if it does i want to put that data into that group. If datum doesn't fit to any of the group, i want to create new group. So, i want to use linked list for the purpose or is there any other way to doing so??

P.S. i have way to check the similarity between data and group representative(lets not go that in deatil for now) but i dont know how to add the data to group (each group may be list) or create new one if required. i guess what i needis linked list implementation in python, isn't it?

Comment: @ Karl Knechtel, i wanna compare the data with each group representaive(may be mean of the cluster or group; to be find out later on) and if data being compared matches with the group representative with provided threshold, then the data can be append as new member of the group...else if check with other groups ...else create new group with the first member of the group being the data ... i hope its clear to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a dictionary (or [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)), where the key is the group and the value is a list of all data.  Here is a simple example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> get_group = lambda x: x % 4
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for value in range(10):
...     d[get_group(value)].append(value)
... 
>>> dict(d)
{0: [0, 4, 8], 1: [1, 5, 9], 2: [2, 6], 3: [3, 7]}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...sorry i hadn't thought about it.. sorry for asking such a simple query.

Comment: @Ajay - No problem, if my solution works for you click on the outline of a check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a perfect use for a dictionary.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i was thinking the simple thing in quite a complex way